# Sending an email with Lotus Notes using Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, lotus-notes

I am using Lotus and wanted to send email via batch file, I tried following command.

```
*D:\lotus\Notes\notes mailto:abc@abc.com?subject="Hello"?body="Test"*
```

The issue is that instead of sending email, Lotus new message GUI opens.

Answer (score 1):

This works as designed.
 in browsers does the same

You could use the notes com objects if you need to send mails.

Comment: or have a look a this http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/command%20line%20email%20client

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my late answer.

Lotus always new message GUI if executing note.exe, so I write a VBScript to solve this problem.

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"YourLotusPath\notes.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
shell.run"YourLotusPath\notes.exe mailto:username@abc.com?subject=Test?body=Test?attach=test.txt"
WScript.Sleep 2000
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
shell.SendKeys"^(+{ENTER})"  <== Ctrl+Shift+Enter, which is lotus "send" shortcut key.
WScript.Sleep 1000
shell.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
```

Then, just execute the VBScript by `cscript sendmail.vbs`

Answer (score 0):

Try this  e.g.:

user needs to be in Lotus Notes directory when executing command

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\Lotus\Notes>notes mailto:email@example.com?subject=My email^&body=some text^&attach=c:\autoexec.bat
```

Comment: What, exactly, is the essence of your suggestion? That the user should be in the Lotus Notes directory when he runs the `notes` command? That subject and body should ***not*** be quoted, even if they contain spaces? That you must include an attachment? Because I don’t see anything else that you’re doing differently from what the OP already tried.

Comment: **Yes , user needs to be in Lotus Notes directory when executing command** . In my example I have used ^ as escape character. Hence If you still want subject and body you'd have to escape the "&" (with ^). Else it is interpreted as a new command. I have just given an example for adding attachments as well if needed.