# Sending emails with lotus notes using windows command line

Tags: command-line, email, lotus-notes

According to [sending an email with lotus notes using windows command line](https://superuser.com/questions/759191/sending-an-email-with-lotus-notes-using-windows-command-line)

Run the command `notes.exe mailto:username@abcabc.com?subject="Test"?body="Test"` in cmd, always open GUI instead of sending email immediately, how to send email in command line without clicking "send" button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [Sendkeys from command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709474/sendkeys-from-command-prompt)

Solve this question: send lotus email with command and do not need to click any button.

Write a vbs script:

```
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.run"YourLotusPath\notes.exe"
WScript.Sleep 1000
shell.run"YourLotusPath\notes.exe mailto:username@abc.com?subject=Test?body=Test?attach=test.txt"
WScript.Sleep 2000
shell.SendKeys"{TAB}"
shell.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
shell.SendKeys"^(+{ENTER})"  <== Ctrl+Shift+Enter, which is lotus "send" shortcut key.
WScript.Sleep 1000
shell.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
```

Then, just execute the vbs script by `cscript sendmail.vbs`